# Logitec mouse (unifying receiver) can't select text, left click select text is glitchy

Tags: keyboard, logitech-mouse, logitech-keyboard

When left click to select a section of text anywhere to highlight it to copy or do anything with it. When I start selecting it works for 1-2 sec then it stopes selecting and then when I continue dragging mouse having left mouse press, it start selecting again for 1-2-3 sec then stopes again.
It's like the mouse is losing connection and reconnects.

Here's a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tH0AMEK9iIeV309ekHqZ4e4ZURUu54HJ/view?usp=sharing) showing how the Mouse Unifier is blinking strangely. This has to be a giveaway what the problem is if some of you can say maybe?

I tried with another Logitech unifying receiver (hardware usb plug)but the same thing happens so it's not a problem with the:
[image]

I have updated all drivers for unifying receiver and the K800 mouse and Keyboard combo but no luck fixing this. This Combo is Keyboard is with backlight and high-end expensive now 3+ years old.

I have updated all Logitech drives

Comment: Update the LogiTech drivers and Windows drivers for mouse and keyboard (if there are Keyboard drivers).  LogiTech has unifying receiver updates.  You should do this update as well.  Perhaps also update machine BIOS as well.

Comment: @John I did updated Mouse built in software driver , Logitech Unifying receiver USB plug driver, The Windows drivers for mouse and keyboard(device manager) can't be updated only uninstalled or look for new updates driver

Comment: What software does this problem occur in? Did you try in other programs yet? Try with Linux (Ubuntu Live USB or the like) – does the problem occur there?

Comment: @DanielB I dont run Linux but thanks I will try the Mouse on another Laptop I have (running win 10)

Comment: It's sort-of important to test it on the same hardware but with a clean operating system. No need to install anything, you just need a decently-sized USB drive.

Answer (score 4):

This problem nearly drove me crazy on Logitech M185 - Trying to select text – having to do it 2-3 or more times before text is selected or employing work around using SHIFT key. Very time consuming. Tried many things such as checking for hairs or lint blocking the sensor on the bottom side, reinstalling/upgrading software, adjusting mouse settings, trying the receiver in other USB slots, trying a second M185 I had, etc.
I discovered a solution as follows: It amounts to cleaning the internal left and right button switches with alcohol spray.
Have done this at least 3 times now. Works immediately 100%, until the next time the problem starts occurring - several months.
I used hand sanitizer alcohol spray (70% isopropanol spray(?)), using either soft cotton ear buds or spray dispenser (both worked).
Remove the mouse top cover (M185) - take out battery to expose a screw. Unscrew with philips-head/star screw driver, slide top cover back to remove.
Look for the 2 click switches corresponding to left and right button. Directly spray or dab top of these with the alcohol. Can wipe off excess (but found don't need to).
Replace cover. Presto! Everything working immediately.
The problem?? Perhaps moisture or dirt in the contacts. Will need to repeat in next few months.
Suggest some design flaw in the M185 allowing this to happen??

Comment: Thanks David! this worked for me too using a logitech M90 mouse with usb cord.
I opened it up and cleaned out the fluff which had built up, no alcohol swabs necessary.

Comment: Same problem solved on G305

Answer (score 1):

I have this same issue with my 4yr old M570. Very glitchy holding the selected text to copy. I have to go back and select more than several times. Truly impacting my production time on dwgs and on writing email. I do not feel confident opening up the case...wouldn't know the first thing to do if it was open. This issue only started a few weeks ago.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try mouse settings in WINDOWS So, Selecting text with mouse not working.
open the Control Panel and launch the interface for mouse settings. Highlight on Buttons tab and enable ClickLock feature. You can also adjust settings length of time, if needed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).